# Writing a shell using C. How to differentiate interactive mode and batch mode

Tags: c, shell, io, stdin

I am writing a shell with both interactive and batch modes in C. I would like to print the prompt in interactive mode and don't show it in batch mode.

i.e.

```
bash> ./myshell
```

should show prompt, and

```
bash> ./myshell < sample.txt
```

should only show the output from the commands in "sample.txt", but not the prompts.

Since the parent process (which is bash) made the stdin redirection, I am not sure how can myshell tell if the input stream was from stdin or from a file?

Thanks very much in advance for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`isatty(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/isatty.html) can be used to determine if a given file descriptor is a [tty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/). Shells will use this to determine what kind of input to expect.

For example:

```
if (isatty(STDIN_FILENO)) {
    // Interactive shell
}
else {
    // Redirected stdin
}
```